# Why does ISO date in Mongodb display one day earlier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The stored date looks like this:

```
...
"date_of_birth" : ISODate("1920-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
...
```

Using moment, it is formatted in the model (in order to populate the input for updating the document) like this:

```
   AuthorSchema
   .virtual('date_of_birth_update_format')
   .get(function(){
      // format in JavaScript date format (YYYY-MM-DD) to display in input type="date"
      return this.date_of_birth ? moment(this.date_of_birth).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '';
   });
```

Retrieved from the collection and displayed, it displays as one day earlier like this:

```
01/01/1920
```

I would appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: what is your timezone? you may need to use `moment-timezone` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date from mongo is always in GMT, and your server might be in other timezone. You need to convert date to GMT before formatting.

```
var moment = require("moment-timezone")

AuthorSchema.virtual('date_of_birth_update_format').get(function(){
 return this.date_of_birth ? moment(this.date_of_birth).tz('GMT').format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Since moment holds require('moment'), are you saying that moment-timezone replaces moment?

Comment: moment-timezone extends moment. so you can replace moment usage with moment-timezone. you will get all the moment's feature

Comment: Thanks. I installed moment-timezone and modified my code as you suggested, except I passed "America/New_York" to tz like this .tz("America/New_York"). Unfortunately, it still displays Jan 1 and not Jan 2 as it is in the db.

Comment: Update. I passed 'GMT' exactly as you suggested, and now it displays Jan  2! Excellent!

Comment: this was one odd case of handling date of birth, were you could use GMT timezone (because time does  not matter). For other use cases you will need to use appropriate timezone as required

Comment: Are you saying that it is correct to pass my timezone to tz, which is what I did at first, and not 'GMT'?

Answer (score 1):

The `Z` in the ISO 8601 format implies 'GMT' i.e. `1920-01-02T00:00:00+0000`. Moment will take your timezone into consideration. If you are in the continental US, your time zone offset is `-0400`—`-0800`.

`1920-01-02T00:00:00Z` = `1920-01-01T6:00:00-0600` In Pacific Standard Time for example.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that I need to modify how the data is saved into Mongodb to reflect US New York time?

Comment: In a manner of speaking. If you want to represent the beginning of the day January 2, 1920 in NY, then yes, that would be `1920-01-02T00:00:00-0500`. It seems like your storing birthdays, so if you want to get very technical, you could use the timezone offset of the place of birth.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the time zone which you are in for example am in India so GMT for me is +5:30 so whenever I retrieve from db I would add up 5:30 to time so that it matches the date and to answer why it storing it a day before because it stores date in ISO format that's why

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I was using EJS to show the date retrieved from the MongoDB database. I'm not sure if the problem is with EJS, but I solved it like this:

All I had to do was to set the timeZone to GMT in the front-end:

```
date.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {timeZone:"GMT", day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year:"numeric"});
```